# pyttsx3 say nothing

Tags: python, oop, pyttsx3

I am making a virtual assistant with python. I used pyttsx3 for talk to me. I wrote pyttsx3 initialisation in oops way. But when I run this code it says nothing. Here is my code.

````py
import pyttsx3

class Speaker:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = pyttsx3.init() # Initializing pyttsx3
        self.voices = self.engine.getProperty('voices')  # Getting voices property
    
    def speaker_config(self):
        ''' Configurations for speaker '''   
        self.engine.getProperty('voices')  
        self.engine.setProperty('voice', self.voices[1].id)  # Changing voice male to female
        self.engine.setProperty('rate', 140)  # Changing the speed
    
    def say(self):
        self.engine.say('hello')
    
s1 = Speaker()
s1.say()```
````

Comment: Are you using Linux?

Comment: Incidentally, it's "OOP," not "OOPS" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `engine.runAndWait()` in order to process all the queued commands as well after doing an `engine.say`:

```
def say(self):
    self.engine.say('hello')
    self.engine.runAndWait()
```

See [documentation](https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html#pyttsx3.engine.Engine.runAndWait).

Comment: OH thsnks dude. I almost forgot it. Thank you very much!